# Can we use Active Directory for Access Control?

Tags: security

We have a quite elaborate set up for Active Directory, and would like to use this to provision & deprovision access to the Control Panel. Would this be possible in Craft core or in a plugin? Are there hooks to use alternative access methods?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not available in the core. There is a [plugin](https://dukt.net/craft/oauth) which deals with OAuth which may help you.

You can view a list of hooks which Craft provides out of the box [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference).

I imagine you will need to develop your own plugin for this. There is some guidance in the Craft documentation on creating hooks/events in a custom plugin if that's the route you'd prefer go down.

Comment: See here for some more information on how you'd approach AD/LDAP in a plugin: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/486/57